# Vuetify v-combobox automatically selects the typed word when updating items

Tags: combobox, vuetify.js

When the user starts to typing something in the v-combobox component, an axios request is sending to search users in the database. The content of the list is updating dynamically. The problem is that when items in the combobox has been updated, it automatically selects the word previously typed by the user and updates v-model (and in my case, it creates a chip on the frontend). How to prevent automatic select when updating items?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a `v-autocomplete` component to get the behaviour you're expecting. You can think of combobox as a select so any input is a change/selection and autocomplete as a text field where input filters the dropdown options.

Comment: In this case, I cannot select an item not from the list. Combobox allows you to do this by clicking enter. This functionality is required.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows.
Changed the `v-combobox` component to `v-autocomplete`. Made a form for adding a new user. Since `v-autocomplete` does not allow displaying items outside of the list, I disabled the display of `v-model` contents using a slot and made a custom display of `v-model` items using `v-chip` component with deletion.